# What does “gallowdance” mean?

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> Dance with me the gallowdance.

This is a piece from [Lebanon Hanover's lyrics](http://lebanonhanover.tumblr.com/post/45758281353/gallowdance-7-dance-with-me-the-gallowdance-as).

Comment: Undoubtedly refers to how the heels kick about after the trapdoor drops

Comment: The hemp fandango; the sisal two-step.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of lyrics/poetry.

Comment: The [Tyburn Jig](http://books.google.com/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PT968&lpg=PT968&dq=dictionary+%22paddington+jig%22&source=bl&ots=_1RCfKuQ4G&sig=e2ewi6zZ-_7N2n92apCsIKMnBck&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nB6fUpqRLoaRhQf8w4DYCA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=dictionary%20%22paddington%20jig%22&f=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to people jerking about while being hanged.  It's interesting because, from what I could gather, people with suspension hangings or short drops shouldn't move much.  Compression of arteries to the brain would cause the body to become sluggish, with little or no ability to struggle.  It does refer to the above mentioned forms of hanging and not Standard or Long Drops, which would break the spinal cord, resulting in instant death, rather than it taking 10-20 minutes to die.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging)